# BCrypt hashing with SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, cryptography, bcrypt

At first, while using SHA256, I could use something like this:

```
     try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StringConnexion"].ConnectionString))
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlCommand command =
                    new SqlCommand("Select * from USERS where LOGIN_NAME = @Login and Mdp = @passweord", conn))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", Username);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", GetHashSha256(Password));

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            ....
```

[BCrypt](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net) in the other hand, will generate a new output each time so comparing to the database will never be successful, how could I proceed in that case?

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the hashed value from the database and use a BCrypt library to Verify the user supplied value against the database value.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Mdp from USERS where LOGIN_NAME = @Login", conn)
// execute your command into a datareader
bool isValid = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, dr["Mdp"].ToString());
```